# Usage and meaning : 寝ろ vs 寝てろ?

Tags: grammar, verbs, manga, aspect, imperatives

[image]
Source: [page 32, Ch.82 of よつばと！](http://raw.senmanga.com/Yotsubato!/82/32)

My translation of the highlighted text bubble is,

> Now, sleep quietly okay.

But I am confused as to why 寝てろ is used here as opposed to 寝ろ? Is it because sleep is a resultant state (something like 知っています or けっこんしています)?

After some probing I came across [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/14804/how-to-translate-%e3%81%a6-form-%e3%82%8d) but it doesn't answer the difference between usage of 〜てろ and 〜ろ form.

What I did come to know is, 寝てろ is a compact form of 寝ていろ which is imperative/command form of 寝ている. All in all, 寝ていろ is something like a command to sleep (or be in state of sleep or keep sleeping?) Why is the progressive form used here? What kind of subtlety does it add?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This type of いる is called [a subsidiary verb](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18952/5010), and what it means roughly depends on the context and the verb type. For details, see: [When is Vている the continuation of action and when is it the continuation of state?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/3122/5010)

寝る is an ordinary action verb like 食べる, 走る or 勉強する. It's not an "instant state-change (aka punctual)" verb like 知る, 結婚する or 倒れる. This means when 寝て (the te-form of 寝る) is followed by いろ (the imperative form
 of いる), it usually means the **continuation** of the action (i.e., "be ～ing"). So 寝ていろ means "Be sleeping" or "Keep sleeping", while 寝ろ just means "Sleep." or "Go to bed."

Comment: I don't know if this deserves a separate question. Is 早く寝てろ idiomatic and grammatical? I know 寝てろ is very common. I was recently corrected by a native speaker friend who said 早く寝てろ was incorrect. They said it should be 早く寝ろ. But Google seems to show millions of hits for that exact phrase. My friend is a native speaker but moved to the US in their teens, so I am not sure if I should take what they say with a grain of salt.

Comment: @EddieKal 早く寝てろ sounds weird to me, too. I found only about 40 hits for this. Did you enclose this in quotes?

Comment: Oh that's probably why. But after putting it in quotation marks I still see some hits. Hmmm. Maybe I should post this as a question

Answer (score 4):

> All in all, 寝ていろ is something like a command to sleep (or be in state of sleep or keep sleeping ?).

Correct. The difference in nuance from 寝ろ is "*keep* sleeping." It implies that she should keep staying in the bed/sleeping bag and sleeping, and won't wake up and make any fuss.