# When is 早く寝てろ used as opposed to 早く寝ろ?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, usage, aspect

This question is about idiomatic usage of language. The grammatical side of the difference between 寝ろ and 寝てろ is clearly explained [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/47458/30454). But I think there is another part of this question: in what situations should one be used over the other? I was recently corrected by a native speaker friend who said 早く寝てろ was incorrect. They said it should be 早く寝ろ. And it prompted me to think if I have been overusing 寝てろ.

Is the use of 早く寝てろ in the two examples shown below idiomatic? Why or why not?

Why does 早く寝てろ sound unnatural in some contexts? And in exactly what situations should we use 早く寝てろ no 早く寝ろ? More generally also: When do we say 寝てろ? When do we say 寝ろ?

Pic 1, [source](https://prcm.jp/album/4dbce2456f7e8)

[image]

Pic 2, [source](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/739716307536093091/)

[image]

Comment: Where does the first image come from? I don't think みんなの迷惑かける is a valid Japanese...

Comment: @broccolifacemask Both are from Google Images.

Comment: @EddieKal they should both have original sources though, presumably. Google Images doesn't tell us much.

Comment: 「俺が家まで送るから、早く寝てろ」の例ですが、どういう状況かわかりませんよね‥？「俺が（後でお前以外の誰かを）家まで送るので、（お前はそれまでに）早く寝ていろ」って意味か、「俺が（今からお前を）家まで送るので、（そのあと俺たちが何かをしている間、お前は）早く寝ていろ」でしょうかね・・・

Comment: @Leebo You are right. Updated!

Comment: I think this is probably the preceding context: [picture](https://prcm.jp/album/4dbce2456f7e8/pic/71372157) @broccolifacemask

Comment: @Chocolate I think they are talking about a ロンT. Please see the comment above.

Comment: ロンTって何だろう、長袖Tシャツ？「お前の家に長袖Tシャツを送る（送付する）」ってこと？

Comment: @Chocolate That seems to be the case...

Answer (score 3):

「早く寝ろよ」は、「今から寝ろ」とか、「今日の夜に早い時間に寝ろ」という場合に使う感じですが、「早く寝てろよ」は、「早く寝て、とある時間には寝ている状態にあれ」と言っている感じがします。

例えば質問の2つ目の例でいうと、

「嘘だろ早く寝てろよ」は、自分が帰ってくる前に早く寝て、自分が帰ってきた時にはすでに寝ているように、という感じがします。

(1つ目の例は、文脈・状況がよくわかりません)

似た例を考えてみました。

「先に行け。/ 先に行って。」-- 今、自分より先に出発するように、ということに焦点を置いている感じです。
「先に行ってろ。/ 先に行ってて。」-- 自分は後から追いつくので、それより先に行って、自分が行った時にはそこにいるように、ということに焦点を置いている感じです。

Answer (score 3):

I would feel "早く寝てろ" natural if the speaker's intention was to express "You should be in bed. You do need to have a rest. I am worried about you."

The phrase sounds very sympathetic. If you just want to say "Go to bed," "早く寝ろ" fits well in most cases.

It is somewhat broken because a straightforward translation would be like "Stay in bed soon," which might be the reason why your friend said it's wrong. This phrase may be the one the speaker cannot help but saying before thinking abount correctness.