# Why present progressive for "永遠に待ってろ"

Tags: japanese-to-english, imperatives

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GE5JYetB5hc

In this exchange from 推しの子, Kana (the red-haired girl) expresses her annoyance to Ruby (the blonde girl) by saying

> "永遠に待ってろ"

How come Kana didn't say "永遠に待て" but instead used present progressive tense? Is that because Ruby was already in the process of waiting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage and meaning : 寝ろ vs 寝てろ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/47448/usage-and-meaning-%e5%af%9d%e3%82%8d-vs-%e5%af%9d%e3%81%a6%e3%82%8d) 待て would sound like the listener has not been waiting.