# The grammar of present progressive in imperative tense -ていろ

Tags: imperatives

What is the nuance  of this sentence here:

> **自分の巣の中で オナニーしていろ 童貞**
>
> Translated as: "Go jerk-off in your nest, you virgin"

Does  **-ていろ**  imply to "to keep on doing something". So that a more literal translation would be: *Keep on jerking-off inside your nest, virgin*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this -ていろ basically has a progressive meaning.

- [Usage and meaning : 寝ろ vs 寝てろ?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47448/5010)
- [How to translate て-form + ろ](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14804/5010)

But いる is also a plain existence verb ("to be", "to stay", "to exist"). In this sentence, the main message conveyed by いろ is "**stay in** your nest" rather than "keep doing that action". The speaker wants him to go away, and what he does is not very important. I think the original translation is more natural.

Comment: So it could have potentially two meanings: 1. Stay and jerk-off inside your nest or 2. Keep jerking-off inside your nest. But here given the context you are of the opinion that it is 1. ?

Comment: @JapaneseLearner Hmm... 歩いていろ just means "Keep walking", but 見ていろ tends to imply "Keep watching" and "Stay, do nothing else" at the same time. 待っていろ also has a nuance of "Stay for a while". It depends on the context. In a rare situation where what he needs to do inside his nest is really important, 2. is a possible interpretation.

Comment: thank you are a legend of Japanese and English. Very impressed !