# Difference between ～てなさい and ～なさい

Tags: imperatives

I encountered this command while reading a piece of fiction:

休んでなさい

I learned that the pre-masu form is used with imperatives using なさい. So, I would have expected 休みなさい. But, here, the て form is used.

Why is the -te form used here? Is there a difference in meaning or nuance between the -te form and pre-masu form when used with なさい? Is this usage a specific and irregular form used only with the verb 休む, perhaps due to the already pre-existing fixed expression おやすみなさい?

Comment: There are a number of related questions about omitting い after a て form, though I'm not sure if any would qualify as duplicates.

Comment: Related: 　https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/47448/5010 
/ https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14804/5010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is so much the difference between the two but rather a combination of the two. Here the て-form is used in the continuous sense, 休んでいる, and the なさい is simply applied to the end. In this case it is telling the person to *continue* to rest, instead of to rest from here on. A more intuitive reading would be like "Just relax. Stay there." This type of request/command comes up here and there in various Japanese phrases. For instance いい子にしてろ (heard in a manga once) "don't act up" or commonly 待ってて "wait there for me." It doesn't carry over to English easily, but once you get the concept it comes quite intuitively.